# What is the role of sound in string theory?

Tags: condensed-matter, string-theory, acoustics

Densely packed strings (perhaps in a fuzzball scenario) should impact one another frequently and transmit sound. If they're densely packed enough, the sounds produced might be affected by the fact that strings instead of particles are colliding. Has anyone done work on the role of sound in string theory or just more generally string theory as condensed matter?

Comment: The rigorous meaning of "colliding strings" is "interacting strings". And of course people have studied those interactions. Any textbook in string theory (say Polchinski) explains the basics of perturbative string theory.

Comment: Sure, but the question is specifically about the collective behavior of strings. A good answer (of a research program in this direction) would be that densely packed strings produce very different sounds that densely pack point particles or alternatively even densely packed strings sound the same as point particle systems. Perturbative string theory is the equivalent how atoms scatter in a gas. I sort of suspect that collectives of strings have some kind of "algorithmic" activity, so the sounds of strings would be more organized.

Comment: For starters would the phonons in string 'matter' be stringy in any way?